# Normalize the data and inverse_transform value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a prediction model and I have to normalize my label, since the loss exploded without normalization. But the problem is that, I use MinMaxScaler to normalize the data_train which is with size (2,10) and my predicted values size is (2,5). So when I want to use `inverse_transform`, I got

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (10,) (2,5).
```

Also my test data is with shape (2,10). Could you please help me with this?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

data_train = np.random.randint(10, size = (2,10))

predicted_values_ = np.random.randint(2, size = (2,5))

# fit transform
transformer = MinMaxScaler()
transformer.fit(data_train)
transformed = transformer.transform(data_train)

## model.... and execution


inverted = transformer.inverse_transform(predicted_values_)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to inverse transform outputs using the statistics computed on inputs?

Comment: I dont have any option. Also the data_test has a different shape with the predicted values and I got error with that.

Comment: The problem is MinMaxScaler computes statistics for all dimensions on inputs. For example, first dimension is normalized with min and max values of the first dimension and so on. It doesn't make sense to pass another matrix with different number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's make some clarification

The normalization or scaling are done for making your machine learning model work better, and with a faster convergence. Given a model that works in vectorial space for instance, scaling make the features have more or less the same impact for the model. If the features have different ranges, the one with the greater range could dominate the training process

Given the premise, the scaling is done **only on the features**, (train and test) and **not on the predictions**

If you check the content of your `transformer` instance, you can see that it cointains info to process the scaling for your features (10 features in this case)

```
transformer.data_min_
array([3., 6., 0., 3., 6., 6., 7., 2., 1., 0.])

transformer.data_max_
array([7., 7., 1., 6., 8., 9., 8., 7., 9., 6.])
```

So for each feature column the scaling is done with the following formula

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

Even if you wanted to calculate the scaling of your predicted values, the domains of your prediction and features are totally different

Take for instance a model that predict if a person is tall (prediction 1) or short (prediction 0) based on the height (feature)

I normalize my height feature that could be something like this

```
height
-----
182
170
120
150
...
135

min = 100
max = 200

height_scaled
------------
0.82
0.7
0.2
0.5
...
0.35
```

Given this scaling, it does not make sense to scale the model output that has a different domain  for construction with the same parameters of your features (your `model.predict`, for a binary classification problem for instance will output by default values in `[0, 1]`)

One thing that you should remember is that the scaler fit should be done only on the train data, and the transforming on both train and test, in order to avoid data leaking on the test set

as example:

```
train_data = ...
test_data = ...

transformer = MinMaxScaler()
# fit only on train data
transformer.fit(train_data )
# scale both train and test
train_data_scaled = = transformer.transform(train_data)
test_data_scaled = transformer.transform(test_data)

# now I train the model
model.fit(train_data_scaled)
prediction = model.predict(test_data_scaled)

# prediction should not be touched
```